# Adding data in intervals in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I have data in MATLAB like this:

```
F =

1.0000    1.0000
2.0000    1.0000
3.0000    1.0000
3.1416    9.0000
4.0000    1.0000
5.0000    1.0000
6.0000    1.0000
6.2832    9.0000
7.0000    1.0000
8.0000    1.0000
9.0000    1.0000
9.4248    9.0000
10.0000    1.0000
```

I am looking for a way to sum the data in specific intervals. Example if I want my sampling interval to be 1, then the end result should be:

F =

```
1.0000    1.0000
2.0000    1.0000
3.0000    10.0000
4.0000    1.0000
5.0000    1.0000
6.0000    10.0000
7.0000    1.0000
8.0000    1.0000
9.0000    10.0000
10.0000    1.0000
```

i.e data is accumulated in the second column based on sampling the first row. Is there a function in MATLAB to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes by combining `histc()` and `accumarray()`:

```
F =[1.0000    1.0000;...
2.0000    1.0000;...
3.0000    1.0000;...
3.1416    9.0000;...
4.0000    1.0000;...
5.0000    1.0000;...
6.0000    1.0000;...
6.2832    9.0000;...
7.0000    1.0000;...
8.0000    1.0000;...
9.0000    1.0000;...
9.4248    9.0000;...
10.0000    1.0000];

range=1:0.5:10;

[~,bin]=histc(F(:,1),range);

result= [range.' accumarray(bin,F(:,2),[])]
```

If you run the code keep in mind that I changed the sampling interval (`range`) to 0.5.

This code works for all sampling intervals just define your wanted interval as `range`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and that's a job for [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

Use the values in column 1 of `F` to sum (default behavior of `accumarray`) the elements in the 2nd column.

For a given interval of size `s` (Thanks to Luis Mendo for that):

```
S = accumarray(round(F(:,1)/s),F(:,2),[]); %// or you can use "floor" instead of "round".

S =

     1
     1
    10
     1
     1
    10
     1
     1
    10
     1
```

So constructing the output by concatenation:

```
 NewF = [unique(round(F(:,1)/s)) S]

NewF =

     1     1
     2     1
     3    10
     4     1
     5     1
     6    10
     7     1
     8     1
     9    10
    10     1
```

Yay!!

Comment: Nice use of `accumarray`! For an arbitrary interval size `s`, you could use `accumarray(round(F(:,1)/s),F(:,2),[])`, or maybe `accumarray(floor(F(:,1)/s),F(:,2),[])`

Comment: Ah yes thanks for that @LuisMendo I didn't think to generalize for an arbitrary interval size :)